# What is the title of this Ming era picture dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, books

I was browsing Wikipedia when I came across this picture:

[image: An excerpt from a 1436 primer on Chinese characters]

([source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chineseprimer3.png))

The description says:

> An excerpt from a 1436 primer on Chinese characters. (better version)
>
> Original picture sourced from:
>
> Ebrey, Patricia. Cambridge Illustrated History of China. Cambridge
>   University Press, June 13, 1996. ISBN 0521435196

But what is the title of the book?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title of the book is [《新編對相四言》明刻本](https://kknews.cc/history/q452j6y.html).