# Monolingual Mandarin illustrated dictionary in traditional characters

Tags: mandarin, traditional-characters, dictionary

Is there any Mandarin picture dictionary that:

- Is 100% in Mandarin (no English or other languages).
- Uses traditional Chinese characters.
- Is available as a physical book.

If possible, there should be no Pinyin, Zhuyin, or other pronunciation aids. Pronunciation aids are a big distraction for my use case.

I intend to read the book on a regular basis to help me retain my vocabulary (character recognition and writing ability) in wide-ranging topics.

(I have something similar for French [*VU: Dictionnaire visuel pour tous*], so I am wondering if there is one for Mandarin too).

Comment: You can find/order Chinese teaching pictorial books from Taiwan. But for such a book, Zhuyin is usually displayed to help the youngsters in learning. I remember there is such a dictionary, but not for every word but plants, animals...etc.

Comment: I believe there are such designed for young native speakers. For traditional Chinese characters, I suggest looking in Hong Kong, Taiwai, Macau, Singapore, Malaysia etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any Mandarin picture dictionary

first of all, mandarin is just one of **spoken languages** used in, . . . china.

anyway, one book mets your criteria (pictorial, in traditional chinese): “新編對相四言”, the internet archive has a copy, which was printed in . . . 1506

https://archive.org/details/ldpd_10820867_000/page/n1/mode/2up

i checked books.com.tw, pictorial dictionaries (“圖解字典”, or “圖畫詞典”) are mostly bilingual, and/or with zhuyin.

these two, in stocks, might suit your needs:

[中國器物圖解詞典](https://www.books.com.tw/products/0010774161)

[中國園林圖解詞典](https://www.books.com.tw/products/0010765489)

have fun :)

Comment: That book is the subject of this question: [What is the title of this Ming era picture dictionary?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35068/what-is-the-title-of-this-ming-era-picture-dictionary)

Comment: @Flux, yes, you get it :)

Comment: Mandarin (国语) is the official Chinese spoken language that differs from local dialects. The teaching of it is mandatory in two main Chinese lands - China and Taiwan.

Comment: @r13, search this site for “spoken language”, “dialect” & “topolect”; **read** the discussions, please 

Comment: Every country has an official language that is taught at school. In the case of China and Taiwan, Mandarin is the only official spoken language., which shouldn't be confused with dialects that are merely spoken locally, or regionally the best. If you are Japanese, I believe it happens in Japan too - only ONE official spoken language, not any dialect.

Comment: I think you know what is an "official spoken language", and why needs one in China.

Comment: @r13 “Every country has **an** official language that is taught at school”? you’re kidding  find info about nepal, and india  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_with_official_status_in_India https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_of_India , again, read and comprehend before making further comment on this thread, **please**

Comment: You are arguing for non-sense. I don't know Nepal, for India - "The 'official language' of the Republic of India is Hindi, with English serving as its auxiliary official language." From time to time you have shown excellent knowledge of Chinese culture/language, I don't know why you didn't get this right.

Comment: @r13, calm down, relax, please. the two wiki pages are not long, easy to read, imo. one might compare the situation in foreign places, to think reflectively. “ The 'official language' of the Republic of India is Hindi, with English serving as its auxiliary official language” again, such description is also, . . . wrong. **read the provided links, please** last, this comment would be my last response to this thread.  life is short 

Comment: In the US, each ethnic group speaks its native language, such as British English, Spanish, French..., do you consider standard American English is a dialect but the official language of the US? Though one day (and it is coming), Spanish could become the auxiliary/second official language because the vast population speaks it.

Comment: I believe you have some Chinese friends, please ask them what spoken language is taught at schools, and speaking in official gatherings, meetings...Mandarin (國語, 普通話) or dialect (方言, 地方話).